# Show that transformation $u=\frac{y}{x^3}, v=\frac{y}{x}$ determines a bijection between $(0, \infty)^2$ and $(0, \infty)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, functions, definite-integrals

I am working on a problem which states:

> Sketch the finite planar region $D$ which is bounded by the four curves
>   $$y = x^3,\space\space y = 10x^3,\space\space y = x,\space\space y = 2x.$$
>   Show that the transformation given by
>   $$u=\frac{y}{x^3},\space\space v=\frac{y}{x}$$
>   determines a bijection between $(0, \infty)^2$ and $(0, \infty)^2.$  Evaluate
>   $$\iint_D \frac{2y}{x^5}\, dx\ dy.$$

I have sketched the four curves, but am struggling with the second part (showing that the transformation determines a bijection).

My thoughts about this part are:

- What does it mean for a transformation to determine a bijection (I know the definition of bijection)?
- I think that $(0,\infty)^2$ refers to the Cartesian product of the set $(0,\infty)$ with itself.  Am I correct?

Comment: Think of a transformation as a function, except that its input and output are ordered pairs, instead of real numbers. And yes, $S^2$ does means the Cartesian product of $S$ with itself. In this case, the notation is used to say that you have ordered pairs of nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: @CarlHeckman: that is helpful.

Comment: @CarlHeckman: do I have the right intuition if I think like this: Let $T$ be the transformation given by $u=\frac{y}{x^3}$, $v=\frac{y}{x}$.  Then $T(x,y)=(u,v)=(\frac{y}{x^3}, \frac{y}{x})$?

Comment: Yes. [And I have to type some more to get the minimum length.]